Second purchase button in shop interface doesn't work
The 1st button works, but the 2nd button doesn't work.
I think the problem is in this part:
if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats").Cash.Value >= v.Cost.Value then

local tycoon = script.Parent.Parent

local mainItems = tycoon:FindFirstChild("MainItems")
local values = tycoon:FindFirstChild("Values")
local Name = script.Parent.Parent.MainItems.Claim.NameBill.NameValue

local buttons = tycoon:FindFirstChild("Buttons")
local purchasedItems = tycoon:FindFirstChild("PurchasedItems")
local objects = {}

mainItems.Claim.ClaimT.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if values.OwnerValue.Value == nil then
        local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
        if player then
            if player:FindFirstChild("hasTycoon").Value == false then
                values.OwnerValue.Value = player
                Name.Text =  player.Name.."'s Tycoon"
                player:FindFirstChild("hasTycoon").Value = true
            end
        end
    end
end)

if buttons then
    for i, v in pairs(buttons:GetChildren()) do
        spawn(function()
            if v:FindFirstChild("Button") then

                local newObject = purchasedItems:FindFirstChild(v.Object.Value)
                if newObject ~= nil then
                    objects[newObject.Name] = newObject:Clone()
                    newObject:Destroy()
                else
                    v:Destroy()
                end

                if v:FindFirstChild("Dependency") then
                    v.Button.Transparency = 1
                    v.Button.CanCollide = false
                    v.BuyButton.BillboardGui.Enabled = false
                    v.BuyButton.Transparency = 1
                    coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
                        if purchasedItems:WaitForChild(v.Dependency.Value) then
                            v.Button.Transparency = 0
                            v.Button.CanCollide = true
                            v.BuyButton.BillboardGui.Enabled = true
                            v.BuyButton.Transparency = 0
                        end
                    end))
                end

                v.Button.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
                    local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)
                    if player then
                        if values.OwnerValue.Value == player then
                            if v.Button.CanCollide == true then
                                if player:FindFirstChild("leaderstats").Cash.Value >= v.Cost.Value then
                                    print("Test")
                                    player.leaderstats.Cash.Value -= v.Cost.Value
                                    objects[v.Object.Value].Parent = purchasedItems
                                    v:Destroy()
                                else 
                                    print("Test2")
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end)
            end
        end)
    end
end

